# Sum column from multiple rows with column equal to column in other table

Tags: mysql, sum, row

I want to display the top 10 summed values of *amount* from table1 for each *userID* in table2 with matching transaction_id.

**dc_comments**

- userID, int(11)
- transaction_id, int(11)

**dc_donations**

- transaction_id, int(11)
- amount, int(11)

How would I go about doing this?

Example:

**dc_comments:**

```
userid, transaction_id
     1, 777
     2, 450
     1, 823
     3, 234
```

**dc_donations:**

```
transaction_id, amount
           777,  3
           450,  5
           823, 40
           234, 10
```

The output should be:

```
 43
 10
  5
```

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a friend, here's the solution

mysql_query("SELECT name,userID,SUM(amount) as total
        FROM dc_comments
        LEFT JOIN dc_donations ON (dc_comments.transaction_id = dc_donations.transaction_id)
        GROUP BY userID ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10");